# Importing a contract from swarm

Tags: swarm

I am trying to import this contract from the swarm node and need to use the functions in this contract but I could'nt import it from swarm using this code

> pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
>
> import {KITTOKEN} from
>   "bzzr://e0368ff5ab815ac687baeecc9261c317ea38117cb46d872cb295ae69500b6c00";
>
> contract KitToken is KITTOKEN{
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any information on doing this natively in Soldity, however the Remix docs say you can import Swarm files using the `bzz` protocol, not `bzzr`. Try changing it to this:

`import {KITTOKEN} from "bzz://e0368ff5ab815ac687baeecc9261c317ea38117cb46d872cb295ae69500b6c00";`